# Undefined reference to ClockCmd compiling a TK application

Tags: gcc, linker, tcl, ld, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to compile an example programme using tk. I have nearly all of the libraries sorted, but I think I'm missing one.

Command:

```
gcc ./tk.c -I/usr/include/tcl8.5/ -ltk8.5 -ltcl8.5 -lm -lpthread -lfontconfig -lX11 -lXft -lXss
```

Output:

```
/tmp/cc78MM6w.o: In function `Tk_AppInit':
tk.c:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `ClockCmd'
tk.c:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `ClockObjDestroy'
tk.c:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `ClockObjCmd'
```

There's nothing on Google -- anyone recognise ClockCmd? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with the example code I think; none of the other examples had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think those are part of the implementation of Tcl, and should not be referred to outside the Tcl library itself. (The linker is instructed to remove the external reference to them when building the DLL/shared object.) Either that or they are part of your code, and you've simply not supplied them for some reason, but I think you'd know if that was the case.

It would be far easier to work out what's going on if we could actually see the code of `tk.c`; it's clearly not part of any Tcl or Tk code distribution.